# Smooth Scrolling in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I came across this article on Codrops about altering the scroll behaviour with smooth easing:
https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SmoothScrollAnimations/

Here is the js file responsible for this subtle effect:
https://github.com/codrops/SmoothScrollAnimations/blob/master/js/demo.js

I would like to learn how to turn this class based oop syntax from vanilla javascript to React.
I already figured out that some custom hooks can comes in handy (**useWindowsSize** or **useOnscroll**) but I can't figured out the way to pass all other class related stuff into a stateless functional component structure.

I know that this is Scrolljacking and it is not supposed to be used in a webpage, but I'm trying to learn how to completely switch to react for my projects.

My question is, how would you refactor this code?

(p.s. I'm not looking for someone to do the job for me. I'm just looking for advice on what is the right way to face this challenge, as now I'm stuck not knowing where to start.)

Comment: Start by disabling the default scroll behavior and create a scrolling effect by setting a `transform` property based on a `wheel` or `scroll` event. Then work from there.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any reference to look at? Article / Video?